# How to apply list of functions cumulatively in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Assume I have input `x` and a list of functions `[f, g, h, j]` is there a TensorFlow function to get the composition of these? i.e. `[f(x), g(f(x)), h(g(f(x))), j(h(g(f(x))))]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python can have callables (i.e., functions) assigned to variables. If you use this feature, you can easily loop through a list of callables to get the composition:

```
def compose(x):
    # For more clarity, let's actually assign callables to variables
    f = tf.nn.leaky_relu
    g = lambda x: -x
    h = tf.nn.sigmoid
    j = tf.reduce_mean

    callables = [f, g, h, j]
    results = []
    for func in callables:
        x = func(x)
        results.append(x)
    return results
```

A parallel form of this, something like `tf.map_fn`, isn't possible in this case, since an element depends on previous elements; the flow is inherently sequential.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely the best way. It would be nice of Tensorflow to have the `tf.scan` function accept a broader set of inputs. For example `tf.scan(lambda initializer, fn: fn(initializer), [lambda x: x + 2, lambda x: x * 2, lambda x: x + 3, lambda x: x * 3], 0)` but the functions can't be converted to a type supported by tensors.